# Merge update not working when run it with procedure oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

**table1**

id     number 
123    100 
124    200

**table2**

id      id_1    type 
123     456     match 
124     455     match2

**table3**

id_1  limit 
456   50

```
MERGE INTO table3 t3
USING (SELECT t1.id, t1.number, t2.id_1 
         from table1 t1, table2 t2 
        where t1.id= t2.id 
          and t2.type='match') temp
on( t3.id_1=temp.id_1)
when matched
then 
update set t3.limit= temp.number
```

This is working perfectly when running merge statement in toad. but when I plugged the same code in package and procedure; data is not being update and procedure
exits gracefully.

any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you create  [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18) to simulate it ?

Comment: Are the changes being committed? Have you tried adding a `commit;` to the end of your procedure?